# String format alignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm baffled on how to solve this formatting issue. I suspect it's because there are two variables present instead of one which in turn throws it all off.

This is my output currently..

```
Bin Range    Count
0-9           1   
20-29          1
```

And I'm trying to achieve..

```
Bin range    Count
0-9            1
20-29          1
```

My code for this segment is..

```
counter = collections.Counter()
for py_filename in glob.glob('*.py'):
    with open(py_filename) as f:
        linecount = sum(1 for line in f)
        counter[linecount//10] += 1

print('\n{0}    {1}'.format('Bin Range', 'Count'))

for i,n in sorted(counter.items()):
    print('{}-{:<12}{:<4}'.format(i * 10, (i + 1) * 10 - 1, n))
```

I assume if the `0-9` part was all one variable, then this wouldn't be an issue but is there a way to *group* two variables under a formatting rule or do I just need to figure out a more effective way of processing my results.

Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just use a sub-format, as in:

```
for i,n in sorted(counter.items()):
    binrange='{}-{}'.format(i*10, (i + 1) * 10 - 1)
    print('{:<12}{:<4}'.format(binrange, n))
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was after, now I'll know for future occasions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `width` a variable dependent on the string length of the first item:

```
In [1]: items = [[0, 9, 1], [20, 29, 1]]

In [2]: for x, y, z in items:
   ...:     print '{}-{:<{width}}{}'.format(x, y, z, width=10-len(str(x)))
   ...:     
0-9        1
20-29      1
```